# Ошибка в функции sort()

Tags: c++

Почему ошибку выдает?

```
class _listAffair : listAffair {
private:
    std::vector<_affair*> list;
public:
    _listAffair() { }

    bool sortP(_affair& right, _affair& left) {
        return right.getPriority() < left.getPriority();
    }

    bool sortT(_affair& right, _affair& left) {
        return right.getTime() < left.getTime();
    }

    virtual void addIn() {
        _affair *t = new _affair();
        list.push_back(t);
    }

    virtual void addIn(std::string _description) {
        _affair *t = new _affair(_description);
        list.push_back(t);
    }

    virtual void sortListPriority() {
        std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), sortP);
    } // error

    virtual void sortListTime() {
        std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), sortT);
    } // error

    virtual void changePriority(int index, int priority) {
        list[index]->changePriority(priority);
    }

    void getInfo() {
        int count = 0;
        for (auto i : list) {
            std::cout << count << ". " << i->getDescription() << " " << i->getTime() << std::endl;
            count++;
        }
    }

    virtual void deleteAffair(int index) {
        if (list[index] != nullptr) {
            delete list[index];
            while (list[index++] != nullptr)
                list[index - 1] = list[index];
        }
    }

    virtual ~_listAffair() {
        for (auto i : list) {
            if (i != nullptr)
                delete i;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: какой текст ошибки?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XxgkT0k

Comment: `sortP` само по себе не является корректным выражением в С++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Методы `sortP` и `sortT` являются нестатическими функциями-членами класса и поэтому имеют скрытый параметр `this`. То есть у этих функций по три параметра, а предикат сравнения для сортировки должен иметь два параметра. Функции с тремя параметрами не могут использоваться в качестве предикатов сравнения для `std::sort`.
2. Идентификаторы `sortP` и `sortT` сами по себе не является корректными выражениями в С++. Поэтому не ясно, что вы хотели сказать этим

   ```
   std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), sortP);
   ```
3. Если ваш вектор содержит указатели `_affair *`, то и ваши предикаты сравнения для сортировки такого вектора должны принимать  `_affair *`. А у вас они почему-то принимают ссылки `_affair &`.